# Trouble with comment notification in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, notifications

I am running a social networking iPhone app using CodeIgniter. All notifications are working perfectly except for one: A user should receive a notification when another user comments on one of their posts, but currently, they are not receiving the notification. Here is the code:

```
function add_comment($postID, $postThumbURL, $postOwnerID, $userID, $username, $photoURL, $comment)
{
    $now = $this->getDate();
    $timestamp = time();
    $sql = "insert into comments values('', '$postID', '$userID', '$now', '$timestamp', '$comment')";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    $commentID = $this->db->insert_id();

    $sql = "update posts set commentCount=commentCount+1 where postID='$postID'";
    $this->db->query($sql);

    $sql = "select c.nID as commentID, c.created_timestamp as created_at, c.comment, c.userID, u.username, u.photoURL from comments c LEFT JOIN users u ON(c.userID=u.id) where c.nID='".$commentID."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $query = $query->result();

    $sql = "insert into notification values('', '$userID', '$postOwnerID', '$postID', '7', '".time()."')";
    $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query[0];
}
```

Any help or advice on fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you need any additional code, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: of the 4 queries, which works\ or not

Comment: What's the point of using a framework if you are not going to use it's input escaping functions for database queries?

Comment: I apologize, this is the one that does not work: '    $sql = "insert into notification values('', '$userID', '$postOwnerID', '$postID', '7', '".time()."')";
    $this->db->query($sql);'

Comment: how can users gets notifications if there is only db insert code? I suppose you might need add some mailing code

Comment: turn on database debugging & test it, if the query fails it should give you an output on what makes it fail. I am against using values directly in query (either use active records or use '?' & pass your values ->query('sql command', array(val1, val2)) ..etc.

Comment: I am against using timestamp, what's wrong with datetime fields? And the way you're adding notifications will just waste your time, I'd make a model & add it in autoload so I can always call a function like $this->notifications->add(arg1, arg2..etc); so you have to debug your notification code once.